# Build system for compiling multiple GNU Autotools projects

Tags: build, build-process, build-automation, autotools

I'm looking for a process to build multiple GNU autotools based projects that are all located in separate source control.

I'm looking for a build framework that I can supply something along the lines of.
Main things I want to specify are repo src (eg. git,hg...), depends.

```
{
  repos : [
     { src : "git://someplace.com/repo1",
       branch : "devel",
       depends : []
     },
     { src : "git://someplace.com/repo2",
       branch : "default" 
       depends : ["repo1"]
     }
  ] 
}
```

Does anyone know with something like that exists? I've used bitbake/openembedded and yocto in past for different embedded projects but I think they are way overkill for what i'm looking for.

Comment: GNU projects typically do not deploy from a vcs, but from a tarball.  Look into `pkgsrc`.

Comment: Completely agree, but for needs it makes more sense to pull directly from a vcs.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Test::AutoBuild](http://www.autobuild.org/index.html) in the past.  According to their feature list they support dependencies, but I haven't tried them.